# NSISdl::download is not working

Tags: nsis

I have written below code to read a text file, which contains the server url and pre calculated md5 sum of update.zip file. The file is named as temp.txt The contents of text files are as below

```
http://10.212.8.230:8080/update.zip
daf6de1b3d8fa32f276e26566311515f
```

I read the text file and save the url string in %path variable. My problem is when I pass this $path to NSISdl::download then it gives me error at run time like 'PKU' something. but when I pass same url hard coded(manually without reading from file then it works). Same case with MD5 sum. I read it from temp.txt file and store in a variable and when I campare the string it shows me not same even when the string is same. But when I give it hard coded then it works.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, where I am doing mistake. I tried my all best but I couldnt fix it. How to read it from text file and pass it to download from server???

```
var path;variable to save download url downloaded from temp.txt file
var downloaded_md5;variable to save md5 sum of update.zip downloaded from temp.txt file
var local_md5;used to store md5 sum of update.zip after downloading the update.zip
Section

   FileOpen $0 "$INSTDIR\temp\temp.txt" r ;reading file
   FileRead $0 $1
   StrCpy $path $1;storing url in $path

   NSISdl::download "$path" "$INSTDIR\temp\update.zip";passing $path to download
   Pop $R0 ;Get the return value
   StrCmp $R0 "success" ExtractFiles

   DetailPrint "Update downloading failed"
   MessageBox MB_OK "Update downloading failed: $R0"
   Quit

ExtractFiles:
    FileRead $0 $1
    StrCpy $downloaded_md5 $1;storing md5 string
    md5dll::GetMD5File "$INSTDIR\temp\update.zip"
    Pop $0
    StrCpy $local_md5 $0

    StrCmp $downloaded_md5 $local_md5 same notsame
    same:
        MessageBox MB_OK "MD5 is same"
        goto End
    notsame:
        MessageBox MB_OK "MD5 is not same"
        goto End
  End:
     Quit
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fileread reads until a newline or null byte is read. The carriage return /lew line characters are included in the resulting string, so you need to trim the string.

See [StrTrimNewLines](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/StrFunc).

Your code should be something like:

```
!include "StrFunc.nsh"
${StrTrimNewLines}

var path;variable to save download url downloaded from temp.txt file
var downloaded_md5;variable to save md5 sum of update.zip downloaded from temp.txt file
var local_md5;used to store md5 sum of update.zip after downloading the update.zip
Section
   FileOpen $0 "$INSTDIR\temp\temp.txt" r ;reading file
   FileRead $0 $1
   ${StrTrimNewLines} $path $1 ;storing url in $path and removing newline
[....]
```

You need to do the same operation when reading the MD5sum.

Comment: Do same with the question, if you feel it was a valid question